# XNA Game Studio 4.0 does not show in installed templates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xna

I've been using XNA Game Studio 4.0 with Visual Studio 2013 Express Desktop Edition for a few weeks now.

Recently, Visual Studio stopped working, saying that it:

> could not find all components

I worked around this problem by choosing "repair" from it's setup.

However, it stopped showing XNA as an installed template.

Things I have already tried:

- Uninstalling and re-installing Visual Studio
- XNA Game Studio

I tried uninstalling XNA Game Studio, but there is no uninstall.exe anywhere, it does not show in "Programs and Features" in Control Panel, and in the Start Menu also it does not have any uninstall features.

As of now, XNA is not part of my installed templates, but it is installed.
When I try to install it again it says

> "This extension is already installed to all applicable products".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

The problem lied in the Visual Studio software, which stopped working and had to be re-installed (as I mentioned earlier).

After that, XNA was still installed but not showing as an installed template.
So, in Visual Studio, I went in **Tools->Extensions and Updates**.
In **installed templates**, it was *empty*.  But after typing "XNA Game Studio" in the search bar, it showed *XNA*.

The problem was, that it was disabled.
Just enable it and it'll start working like perfect and show up in your installed templates.

I really appreciate the help given to me by **@Salah Akbari**. Seriously, all suggestions and help is really appreciated.

Comment: _"Tools->Extensions and Updates. In installed templates, it was empty"_ - yes I've run into that.  I wish they fix it.  By the way, don't forget you can **mark your own answer as the solution**, giving yourself nice brownie points in the process :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 8, XNA is not supported on Windows 8. There is a work around:

> - Download and install Games for Windows Marketplace Client

You can find it in the following link.:

[Games for Windows Marketplace Client](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient)

Comment: I appreciate your response, user2946329.

Comment: It used to work on my system. I had Visual Studio Express 2013 Desktop Edition along with XNA Game Studio 4.0.  Before Visual Studio started showing the error I mentioned earlier, it used to work perfectly. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: your mean is: After installing this software that I mentioned your problem was solved?

Comment: No, I'm sorry I was not clear. I meant that I cannot use the software as I have not got Windows 8. I in fact have Windows 7. The problem remains that I can't launch the XNA VISX launcher, as it keeps saying that it is downloaded in all applicable software, when it in fact is not! I used a variety of XNA Game Studio Cleanup softwares, but they did not do the trick either. XNA is not on my system, but it keeps saying that it is! I cannot re-install it, and no matter how much I re-install Visual Studio, XNA VISX installer keeps giving the same message!